Combining multiple lines into a single event in Filebeat and filtering out unwanted lines
I'm trying to configure Filebeat to combine multiple lines into a single event and filter out unwanted lines.
My data looks like this:
632.5,684,0.984,0.641,0.228,L5B_CG,96.921
240.1,694,0.197,0.183,0.0241,L1D_CG,170
593.6,1021,0.131,0.183,0.0241,L2D_CG,161.250

,,너비,높이,결함 영역,,평균 명암도
,,,,,,
,,mm,mm,mm²,,
506.2,5,0.292,0.183,0.0321,,200.167
184.7,24,0.350,0.275,0.0802,,208.600
376.7,36,0.467,0.458,0.161,,202.400

after in filebeat message output just one event
"632.5,684,0.984,0.641,0.228,L5B_CG,96.921
240.1,694,0.197,0.183,0.0241,L1D_CG,170
593.6,1021,0.131,0.183,0.0241,L2D_CG,161.250
506.2,5,0.292,0.183,0.0321,,200.167
184.7,24,0.350,0.275,0.0802,,208.600
376.7,36,0.467,0.458,0.161,,202.400"

tried config

multiline.pattern: '^\['
multiline.negate: true
multiline.match: after
multiline.max_lines: 50000

processors:
\- script:
lang: javascript
id: filter_lines
source: \>
function process(event) {
var lines = event.Get("message").split("\\n");
var filteredLines = lines.filter(function(line) {
return /^\[0-9\]/.test(line);
});
event.Put("message", filteredLines.join("\\n"));
}

I ran filebeat use this config
fileat closed when read txt file
please help me

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
